# C#: Brute Force with pattern

Tags: c#, brute-force

I wonder if anyone could help me out here. I'm trying to do a brute-force algorithm that will follow a specific pattern.
I can make it output the pattern with some sloppy code work but this stuff is kind of new to me. I have really no idea how to go on from here. If you have an idea how I could do this, I would really apreciate it.

The pattern looks like this

> **AA0AA0A0**

So I want it to bruteforce from **AA0AA0A0** and up to **AA9AA9A9** then will it go to **AA0AA0B0**

I would highly appreciate all suggestions. I have tried to google some solution, but not really found anything special.

**Explanation of the process:**
Starts with generating the first string AA0AA0A0.
Then it generates all the way up to AA0AA0A9.
Then it start with the next number so it would be AA0AA1A0.
So it will count up all the way to AA9AA9AA9 which would result it to jump to AA0AA0B0.

Also updated the code so it's working now.

```
private static char[] fCharList = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    private static char[] fNumList = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartBruteForce(8);
    }

    public static void StartBruteForce(int length)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        char currentChar = fCharList[0];
        char currentNum = fNumList[0];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(currentChar);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(currentNum);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(currentChar);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(currentNum);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(currentChar);
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(currentNum);
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(sb);
        //Console.ReadLine();

        ChangeCharacters(7, sb, length);
    }

    private static StringBuilder ChangeCharacters(int pos, StringBuilder sb, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= sb.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            //sb.setCharAt(pos, fCharList[i]);

            sb.Replace(sb[pos], fNumList[i], pos, 1);
            //sb.Replace(sb[pos], fCharList[i], pos, 1);

            if (pos == length - 1)
            {
                // Write the Brute Force generated word.
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeCharacters(pos - 1, sb, length);
            }
        }

        return sb;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of `for` loops which will either run exactly once `for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)` or not at all `for (int i = 2; i <= 1; i++)`? Also where is this sequence supposed to *start*? with just `A`??

Comment: And, aside from that - your code has a runtime error - http://rextester.com/WBCWU66702

Comment: I dont really know why the whole thing got into a big mess. but the start string would AA0AA0A0.

Comment: So the second string is `AA0AA0A1`?? Then through `AA0AA0A9` to ... `AA0AA0AA`? (Your pattern is hard to understand)

Comment: Yes it would be and the error is beacuse i put in wrong pos on ChangeCharacters.
AA0AA0A0
AA0AA0A9
AA0AA1A0

Comment: First try to describe exactly how the progression should work. Your question doesn't make that very clear, and in programming your first requirement is to know what the code you are about to write actually needs to do. You can't figure out how to solve a problem before you're completely clear on what the problem actually is, especially something like this where there aren't even multiple parts you can work on independently.

Comment: Does it have to be a string? This would be pretty easy in an integer

Comment: Yes it has to be a string. Yeah i updated the Post to be abit more clear about the process.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to split the pattern in two; one for the digits, and one for the chars. The digits progress from `000` to `999`, and the chars from `AAAAA` to `ZZZZZ`. You then just have to splice the digits into the right places of the chars.

```
IEnumerable<string> Strings()
{
    var digits = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    var chars = Enumerable.Range((int)'A', (int)'Z' - (int)'A' + 1).Select(i => (char)i).ToArray();
    for (var c = 0L; c < Math.Pow(chars.Length, 5); ++c)
    {
        var cstr = chars[(c / (chars.Length * chars.Length * chars.Length * chars.Length) % chars.Length)].ToString()
                 + chars[(c / (chars.Length * chars.Length * chars.Length) % chars.Length)]
                 + chars[(c / (chars.Length * chars.Length) % chars.Length)]
                 + chars[(c / (chars.Length) % chars.Length)]
                 + chars[(c % chars.Length)];

        for (var i = 0L; i < 999; ++i)
        {
            var istr = (i / 100 % 10).ToString()
                     + (i / 10 % 10).ToString()
                     + (i % 10).ToString();

            var str = cstr.Substring(0, 2) + istr.Substring(0, 1) + cstr.Substring(2, 2) + istr.Substring(1, 1) + cstr.Substring(4, 1) + istr.Substring(2, 1);
            yield return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Using it it like this:

```
var early = Strings().Take(15);
var late = Strings().Skip(1234).Take(15);
foreach (var s in early.Concat(late))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

will print this:

```
AA0AA0A0
AA0AA0A1
AA0AA0A2
AA0AA0A3
AA0AA0A4
AA0AA0A5
AA0AA0A6
AA0AA0A7
AA0AA0A8
AA0AA0A9
AA0AA1A0
AA0AA1A1
AA0AA1A2
AA0AA1A3
AA0AA1A4
AA2AA3B5
AA2AA3B6
AA2AA3B7
AA2AA3B8
AA2AA3B9
AA2AA4B0
AA2AA4B1
AA2AA4B2
AA2AA4B3
AA2AA4B4
AA2AA4B5
AA2AA4B6
AA2AA4B7
AA2AA4B8
AA2AA4B9
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative solution:

```
var results = from a0 in charList
              from a1 in charList
              from a2 in charList
              from a3 in charList
              from a4 in charList
              from a5 in numList
              from a6 in numList
              from a7 in numList
              select "" + a0 + a1 + a5 + a2 + a3 + a6 + a4 + a7;
```

Again, a nice one-statement solution thanks to LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading my article on how to compute a Cartesian product:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Now it should be clear how to proceed:

```
var results = from product in CartesianProduct(
              new[] { charList, charList, charList, charList, charList, numList, numList, numList } )
              let a = product.ToArray()
              select "" + a[0] + a[1] + a[5] + a[2] + a[3] + a[6] + a[4] + a[7];
```

Behold the power of LINQ: solving your combinatorics problems in a single statement.

Comment: The `select` can just be `string.Concat(a);`, no?

Comment: @Servy: No. Read that last line more carefully! :-)

Comment: Could you not reorder the lists when constructing the array, rather than in the select?

Comment: @Servy: I'm not quite following you. I don't see how to do that and still get the sequence in the order the original poster expects, but I may be missing something obvious. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: `var results = CartesianProduct(new[] { charList, charList, numList, charList, charList, numList, charList, numList } ).Select(product => string.Concat(product);`

Comment: @Servy: The OP wants the numbers to go 000 to 999 *first* before the rightmost A goes to B. Why? Who can say?  But that's the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you have a function that returns the next "pattern" string, so you can have a single for loop.

Something like this:

```
public static string Next(string pattern)
{
    bool carry = true;
    var sb = new List<char>();
    int t;
    for(int i = pattern.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!carry)
        {
            sb.Insert(0, pattern[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (char.IsDigit(pattern[i]))
        {
            t = int.Parse(pattern[i].ToString()) + 1;
            if (t == 10)
            {
                sb.Insert(0, '0');
                carry = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Insert(0, t.ToString()[0]);
                carry = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            t = (int)pattern[i] + 1;
            if (t == 91)
            {
                sb.Insert(0, 'A');
                carry = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Insert(0, Convert.ToChar(t));
                carry = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return new string(sb.ToArray());
}
```

Check the [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dua7o2)

Comment: Thanks man this was just the thing i was looking for :) Will take some time studying this now :)

Answer (score 0):

Some simple loops will iterate over and build a new string each time.  you can convert chars to int and back. So you can treat each letter as a number.  This assumes your pattern is always AA0AA0A0.  If that changes you would need to make the program smarter.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var results in BruteForce())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(results);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<String> BruteForce()
{
    const int firstLetter = 'A';
    const int lastLetter = 'Z';
    for (var firstPos = firstLetter; firstPos <= lastLetter; firstPos++)
    {
        for (var secondPos = firstLetter; secondPos <= lastLetter; secondPos++)
        {
            for (var thirdPos = 0; thirdPos <= 9; thirdPos++)
            {
                for (var fourthPos = firstLetter; fourthPos <= lastLetter; fourthPos++)
                {
                    for (var fifthPos = firstLetter; fifthPos <= lastLetter; fifthPos++)
                    {
                        for (var sixthPos = 0; sixthPos <= 9; sixthPos++)
                        {
                            for (var sevethPos = firstLetter; sevethPos <= lastLetter; sevethPos++)
                            {
                                for (var eighthPos = 0; eighthPos <= 9; eighthPos++)
                                {
                                    yield return
                                        String.Join(string.Empty, 
                                            (char) firstPos,
                                            (char) secondPos,
                                            thirdPos,
                                            (char) fourthPos,
                                            (char) fifthPos,
                                            sixthPos,
                                            (char) sevethPos,
                                            eighthPos);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<String> loop()
{
    char[] chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        string s = string.Format("aa{0}aa{1}{2}{3}", (i % 1000) / 100, (i % 100) / 10, chars[(i % 10000) / 1000], i % 10);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        yield s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

- Make a counter that goes up from 0 to 10 * 10 * 10 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 26 - 1.  It should be a long.
- On each tick of the counter, let the number be `c`.  The bottom digit is `'0' + c%10`.  The next digit is `'0' + c/10%10`.  The next is `'0' + c/(10*10)%10`.  The bottom letter is `'A' + c/(10*10*10)%26`.  The next letter is `'A' + c/(10*10*10*26)%26`.  And so on.
- Put the letters and digits together in the right order and yield the result.

Turning this into code is left as an exercise.